# Expand view in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Views in iOS have the option to "Clip Subviews" which hides everything that overflows the view height. Is there any option for the opposite? I mean, instead of hiding the content, I'd like the view to expand vertically to accomodate the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `autoresizingMask` property on `UIView` to get the desired behavior:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

If this doesn't do what you want, the only other option you have (AFAIK) is to subclass `UIView` and override `-layoutSubviews`.